# How to transfer apps from an emulator to another one, on my PC?

Tags: applications, android-emulator, data-transfer, emulators

I tried to transfer my apps that I already downloaded using blue stacks to another emulator that's **Droid4x**, but I can't find my apps in form of "**.apk**".

How to transfer the apps?